# Using lm() with just one variable in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I've got some baseball stats, RBIs by season, let's say:

```
player      s1  s2  s3
Brian_Giles 66  68  70
Joe_Thomas  71  72  71
Robin_Yount 71  69  68
Jim_Jones   66  66  65
```

And I want to do a simple linear regression using lm() on this data to predict their RBI #s in a 4th season.  Would I need another variable here to create my formula?  How would I most simply complete this linear regression?

I'm trying to work off of this tutorial (http://www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/simpleLinRegExample1.txt), which seems like I might need a second variable, (I'm new to linear regressions, obviously) but I can't figure out what it should be.  The slope of a best-fit line for those three seasons of data?

Comment: If this is just a question about statistical data modeling, then it belongs on [stats.se]. You should know what model you want to use on your data before you fit it in R.

Comment: Understood.  I'll move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do this in R:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "player      s1  s2  s3
Brian_Giles 66  68  70
Joe_Thomas  71  72  71
Robin_Yount 71  69  68
Jim_Jones   66  66  65", header = TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(DF, id = "player", variable.name = "season")
DF$season <- as.integer(DF$season)

fit <- lm(value ~ season * player, data = DF)
summary(fit)
setNames(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(player = unique(DF$player),
                                  season = 4)),
         unique(DF$player))
#Brian_Giles  Joe_Thomas Robin_Yount   Jim_Jones 
#   72.00000    71.33333    66.33333    64.66667
```

By providing an answer I don't endorse your choice of method.

Comment: Thanks!  I know this method isn't ideal for the data, just tried to give basic dummy data so I could best understand the process.  Thanks again for the clear response.